# Rectangular zoom in using jQuery

Tags: jquery, zooming

How I am able to zoom in on a rectangular area on an image using jQuery?

[image]

I don't need the selection functionality working, just need to have a code that zoom in that area on ONE image by defining the correct position and scale.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function for this.

You'll want to animate the [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) property of your image, and the [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property.

I personally use this extension for animations, since CSS3 transitions are generally smoother:

https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced/